# Join two table into one without cross data

Tags: php, mysql

I need an advice how is it better to do.

I have two tables 'shop' and 'office'. They both have column 'ad_id' but the do not cross with each other. I need to get sum of the shop ads and office ads. 
How is it better to do:

- Make two queries and sum them in php
- Make one query and sum them in mysql

As long as i know I cannot join them with left join or similar because they do not have cross data and so I can do this only this way:

```
SELECT count(*) + (SELECT count(*) FROM shop) FROM office
```

How it is better to do? Is there a way to do it better or if not - which one should be faster?

Comment: never #1. php is a limping engine compared to the beast known as mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How it is better to do?** 
let the database do the math it's good with working in sets

**Is there a way to do it better or if not - which one should be faster?**
Typically doing the set based processing in the database before it transmits unnecessary data or calls over a network is best.

Something as simple as this should work... (in mySQL)

```
  SELECT (select sum(amt) from shop) + (select sum(amt) from office)
```

working example: [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcc51/14/0)

it would return the sum of all records from office and shop using shop_ads and office ads columns, add the results together and return 1 figure.

Comment: well conceptually. not exactly as he wrote it.

Comment: @DrewPierce how should be exactly?

Comment: two separate stmts, add the 2 ints. pretty much like he had it. just 2 calls

Comment: ...except, unless I missed something, I am guessing SUM is inappropriate.

Comment: Updated to work via sum.  I assumed sum over count as you indicated you were were adding ads I envisioned this as a sum not a count. the SQL shows count so maybe it's a count of adds instead... regardless, the above method would sum or count values and add the results together in one call.

Comment: you actually get that to work in a mysql database as a single statement? never seen such a thing

Comment: Yep, look at the fiddle.

Comment: oh, i see the fiddle is different. might wanna update your answer !

Comment: D'oh! Updated  I thought I had when I posted the fiddle.  My bad.

Comment: @xQbert Big thanks to you. This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

For a speed test:

```
create table a2
(
    r int not null
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure jamInRandom ()
BEGIN
    declare iCount int;
    set iCount=1;
    WHILE iCount<=100 DO
        insert a2(r) values (rand()*424+1);
        set iCount=iCount+1;
    END WHILE;
    set iCount=1;
    WHILE iCount<=6 DO
        insert into  a2(r) select r from a2;
        set iCount=iCount+1;
    END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

call jamInRandom(); -- call stored proc

select count(*) from a2;    -- 6400 rows (100 random)
select count(*) as theCount,sum(r),avg(r),min(r),max(r) from a2;

+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------+
| theCount | sum(r)  | avg(r)   | min(r) | max(r) |
+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------+
|     6400 | 1279360 | 199.9000 |      6 |    424 |
+----------+---------+----------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Now try that in a php loop, set your stop watch**

```
-- clean up:
-- drop procedure jamInRandom;
-- drop table a2;
```

change last while loop from a 6 to a 10, and I get:

```
+----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+
| theCount | sum(r)   | avg(r)   | min(r) | max(r) |
+----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+
|   102400 | 21538816 | 210.3400 |     11 |    424 |
+----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```